# can't get phone number to launch an automatic call in google actions (nodeJs)

Tags: android, actions-on-google

I want to trigger an automatic call using a platform like twilio when saying "make a call" in the conversation. I have the destination phone and want to have the phone number of the user.  This is available on alexa platform through Amazon account but with Google accounts, I don't find any trick.
Is there any google API to get it ?
Looking to permissions, I don't see a permission like "Read phone number" like location one.
Could you please help me ? We are in the era of automation, what is the reason to not have a permission like that ?

I don't want to initialize a phone call (this is done through twilio). I only want a permission to get the phone number (null or setted) like the permission one for latitude/longitude in the google actions . https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/permissions?hl=en

Comment: The system may not have it.  You can have a Google account without giving them your phone number (I haven't).  And the phone itself, as weird as this sounds, may not know its own number.  SIM cards can be set up such that they don't know the phone number of their own device.  So in that case, the platform has no way to get the user's number.  You see this as a general problem in Android apps-  there's a function to return the user's number if available, but it does sometimes return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform does not have an API to programmatically initialize a phone call nor request a phone number.

Comment: I don't want to initialize a phone call (this is done through twilio). I only want a permission to get the phone number (null or setted) like the permission one for latitude/longitude in the google actions . https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/permissions?hl=en

Comment: There is no permission to get the local device phone number.

Comment: no api = no permission = no automation = do it manually with google in 202x = security before technology